# Задан текст. Напечатать все слова, в которых повторяется первая буква слова

Tags: c++, c, строки

Без функций strlen и тд не получается пробежаться по тексту через *ptr
ptr у меня выделяет целые слова и моя попытка реализовать через ptr не удачно, помогите, пожалуйста. Исправьте код

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGNS
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
using namespace std;

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int strLength(const char* str) {
    int counter = 0;
    while (str[counter] != '\0')
    {
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}

char* mystrtok(char* s, char d)
{
    static char* input = NULL;
    if (s != NULL)
        input = s;
    if (input == NULL)
        return NULL;


    char* result = new char[strLength(input) + 1];
    int i = 0;
    for (; input[i] != '\0'; i++) {

        if (input[i] != d)
            result[i] = input[i];


        else {
            result[i] = '\0';
            input = input + i + 1;
            return result;
        }
    }
    result[i] = '\0';
    input = NULL;
    return result;
}



int main() {

    setlocale(0, "ru");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int n = 0, d = 0;
    char s1[40];
    char s2[40];
    char t[] = "язык рекламных текстов выделяется на фоне других функциональных образований, которые можно отнести к массовой информации применяемых в системах коммуникации.Основная цель рекламы заключается в оповещении возможных и реальных покупателей о преимуществах определенного продукта, идеи или услуг.";
    d = strLength(t);
  
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
    {
        cout << t[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
    {
        if (t[i] == ',' || t[i] == '.' || t[i] == '!' || t[i] == '?' || t[i] == '-') {
            t[i] = ' ';
        }
    }
    
    char* ptr = mystrtok(t, ' ');
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        n = strLength(ptr);
        strcpy(s1,ptr);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
            {
                if (s1[i] == t[d]&& t[d] != *ptr) {
                  
                }
            }
            
        }
        ptr = mystrtok(NULL, ' ');
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
    {
        cout << t[i];
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну что ж, взялся помогать - помогай)) Вот вам третий вариант текста, на этот раз без классов и списков - только циклы и указатели (надеюсь, с ними у вас не будет проблем)...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define TARGET_TEXT "язык рекламных текстов выделяется на фоне других функциональных образований, которые можно отнести к массовой информации применяемых в системах коммуникации.Основная цель рекламы заключается в оповещении возможных и реальных покупателей о преимуществах определенного продукта, идеи или услуг."
#define MAX_WORD_LEN 127   //максимальная длина слова (должно быть не менее 3)
#define MAX_WORDS    4096  //максимальное число слов в нашей строке

//состояния цикла разбора строки на отдельные слова
enum STATE
{
    BETWEEN_WORDS,  //между словами
    IN_WORD         //внутри слова
};

//структура слова
struct WORD_ENTRY
{
    bool        bPrinted; //true для уже напечатанных слов, false - слово ещё не было напечатано
    char*       pWord;  //указатель на первый символ слова в строке
    int         length; //длина слова
};


//функция для печати слова на экран
void PrintWord(WORD_ENTRY* pWE)
{
    char word_buf[MAX_WORD_LEN+1];

    pWE->bPrinted = true;    //помечаем, как напечатанное
    int len = pWE->length;

    if (len <= MAX_WORD_LEN) 
    {
        //если длина слова меньше, чем максимальная - печатаем его полностью
        snprintf(word_buf, len+1, "%s", pWE->pWord);
        printf("%s ", word_buf);
        return;
    }

    //если длина превышает максимальную - печатаем часть слова с троеточием
    //(ну типа для того, чтобы было видно, что напечатана только часть слова)
    snprintf(word_buf, MAX_WORD_LEN-3+1, "%s", pWE->pWord);
    printf("%s... ", word_buf);
};


//возвращает true, если символ c является буквой, false иначе
bool IsWordChar(char c)
{
    if (((c>='A')&&(c<='Z')) ||
        ((c>='a')&&(c<='z')) ||
        ((c>='А')&&(c<='Я')) ||
        ((c>='а')&&(c<='я')) ||
        ((c>='0')&&(c<='9'))) return true;

    return false;
}


int main()
{
    char        t[] = TARGET_TEXT;
    char*       pWord;
    char        c, first_char;
    WORD_ENTRY  word_entries[MAX_WORDS]; //массив слов

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    char* pChr = t-1;
    int   numWords = 0;  //счётчик слов
    STATE state = BETWEEN_WORDS; //начальное состояние - "между словами"
    pWord = t;           //обманываем IDE

    //разбиваем строку на слова
    while (true)
    {
        c = *(++pChr); //читаем очередной символ строки

        switch (state)
        {
        case BETWEEN_WORDS: //мы между словами
            if (IsWordChar(c))
            {
                //если прочитали букву, то значит это первый символ слова.
                //Проверяем счётчик слов, и если он не превышает максимальное значение, 
                //то запоминаем указатель на этот символ и переходим в
                //состояние "в слове"
                if (numWords==MAX_WORDS)
                {
                    printf("Sorry, too many words in text!\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                pWord = pChr; //запоминаем позицию первого символа в слове
                state = IN_WORD;
                continue;
            }
            break;

        case IN_WORD:  //мы в слове
            if (IsWordChar(c)) continue; //если очередной символ - буква, то ничего не делаем (мы по-прежнему в слове)

            //прочитали не букву - слово закончилось.
            //Заполняем поля новой структуры слова, увеличиваем счётчик слов,
            //и снова переходим в состояние "между словами"
            word_entries[numWords].bPrinted = false;
            word_entries[numWords].pWord = pWord;
            word_entries[numWords].length = pChr - pWord;
            ++numWords;
            state = BETWEEN_WORDS;
            break;
        }

        //проверяем символ на конец строки
        if (c=='\0') break;  //конец строки - выход из цикла
    }

    //Начинаем цикл вывода слов на экран
    WORD_ENTRY* pWE = word_entries;  //указатель на текущую структуру слова
    WORD_ENTRY* words_out = word_entries + numWords; //указатель за массив структур (правая граница массива)

    //последовательно перебираем слова - от первого до последнего
    for (; pWE<words_out; ++pWE)
    {
        if (pWE->bPrinted) continue; //если слово уже было напечатано, пропускаем его

        //запоминаем первый символ слова
        first_char = pWE->pWord[0];

        //во внутреннем цикле перебираем все последующие слова на
        //предмет совпадения первого символа
        for (WORD_ENTRY* pWE2=pWE+1; pWE2<words_out; ++pWE2)
        {
            if (pWE2->bPrinted) continue; //если уже напечатано - пропуск

            if (pWE2->pWord[0]==first_char)
            {
                //нашли второе слово, первый символ которого совпал -
                //печатаем оба слова...
                PrintWord(pWE);
                PrintWord(pWE2);

                //...и все последующие слова с совпавшим первым символом
                while ((++pWE2) < words_out)
                {
                    if (pWE2->bPrinted) continue;
                    if (pWE2->pWord[0]==first_char) PrintWord(pWE2);
                }

                //печатаем перевод строки и прерываем внутренний цикл
                //(снова возвращаемся во внешний)
                printf("\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Будет выведено:

```
рекламных рекламы реальных
выделяется в в возможных
фоне функциональных
образований отнести оповещении о определенного
которые к коммуникации
можно массовой
информации и идеи или
применяемых покупателей преимуществах продукта
```

Замечу, что в этом варианте порядок цепочек из слов с одинаковыми первыми буквами получился иным, так алгоритм здесь срабатывает на первые слова в этих цепочках, а не на вторые, как это было в предыдущей версии. Но в остальном - результат тот же.

Comment: Сам текст:
" язык рекламных текстов выделяется на фоне других функциональных образований, которые можно отнести к массовой  .... преимуществах определенного продукта, идеи или услуг." Вывод мне нужен такой, чтобы первый раз он пробегался по словам, когда он нашел первое слово, он проверяет ее первую букву , затем он с этим  словом и первой буквой пробегается по всему тексту отбирая только те слова с которыми совпала первая буква и выписывает  эти слова, потом он берет уже второе слово и делает все тоже самое

Comment: @Рауль если вы приведёте исходное задание, будет намного больше проку. Ну или хотя бы добавите примет того вывода, который требуется.

Comment: Допустим это текст "привет как дела, что делаешь. делать мне еще много и я не хочу об этом говорить" Вывод будет такой :дела делать  мне много  
Смысл того какая функция выполняется ,мы берем каждое слово по отдельности допустим щас берём первое слово " Привет " узнаем ее первую букву - это буква "П" затем мы с этим словом и первой буквой проходим проверку по тексту (по каждому слову) если нашлось такое слово в котором первая буква "П" то выписываем эти слова алгоритм на этом закончен, потом мы проверяем уже следующие слово "как" первая буква"К" проходим весь текст и ищем первую букву в слове

Comment: @Рауль ОК, так намного понятнее. "Немножечко" модифицировал код.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! какую программу используете для с++ ? у меня просто в visual studio это не запускается и ошибки выдает. Первая ошибка не удалось создать код, вторая используется потенциально неинициализированная локальная переменная указатель  pWord. Пожалуйста, если вы можете написать код в таком же формате, как я написал, то напишите так. Просто я совсем новенький в программирование, и не понимаю классы и тд. Я имею ввиду, что если вы можете написать через char то напишите, пожалуйста.  Я просто не могу понять такой синтаксис на данный момент и сдавать функции которые мы не проходили тоже

Comment: @Рауль могу предположить, что ваша ide не понимает, где именно инициализируется переменная pWord и по-этому лепит ошибку. Сам пользуюсь пакетом MinGW, у меня таких проблем не возникает. Попробуйте перед циклом `while` написать `pWord = t; first_char = 'a';`, может тогда всё скомпилируется. Без классов и списков вариант напишу, если будет время...

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло, вы можете написать тоже самое только без классов и тд? я их не понимаю пока совсем

Comment: @Рауль напишу, но только завтра

Comment: @Рауль Обновил ответ, надеюсь вам поможет.

Comment: Спасибо, стало чуть яснее,тяжко пока  понимать особенно, назначение некоторых функций bool IsWordChar(char c)
{
    if (((c>='A')&&(c<='Z')) ||
        ((c>='a')&&(c<='z')) ||
        ((c>='А')&&(c<='Я')) ||
        ((c>='а')&&(c<='я')) ||
        ((c>='0')&&(c<='9'))) return true;

    return false;
} для чего она нужна?

Comment: @Рауль Функция `bool IsWordChar(char c)` возвращает `true`, если переданный ей символ `c` является буквой английского или русского слова - т.е. все символы от `'a'` до `'z'` (англ.) или от `'а'` до `'я'` (рус.), большие или маленькие. Это и прописано в конструкции `if(...) return true;`. Для всех других символов возвращается `false` (пробелы, знаки препинания, прочие, не являющиеся буквами символы, которые мы считаем разделителями между словами). Советую вам детально разобраться в этой программе, что делает и для чего нужна тут каждая строка. Сложно только по началу, потом может увлечь))

Comment: Здравствуйте, вы бы могли бы написать комментарии к коду, а то я уже 2 сутки пытаюсь разобраться, но не выходит. p.s я просто новенький в с++

Comment: если вы можете ориентируйтесь на мой старый код, то что я написал сам, я понимаю , вот такой объем информации мне сейчас доступен по программированию

Comment: @Рауль комментарии к коду написал, как сумел. Надеюсь, вам легче будет разобраться. Успехов.